# What input does my user defined function in spark dataframe take in?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to combine the two columns "Format Group" and "Format SubGroup" to a single column called Format.
The O/P in the final Format column should be in the form of Format Group:Format Subgroup

I need to create my own UDF using some given data, but I am not sure why my UDF doesn't like the input I have given it.

This is the first rows of the data I use:

**checkoutDF**:

```
BibNumber, ItemBarcode, ItemType, Collection, CallNumber, CheckoutDateTime
1842225, 0010035249209, acbk, namys, MYSTERY ELKINS1999, 05/23/2005 03:20:00 PM
```

**dataDictionaryDF:**

```
Code, Description, Code Type, Format Group, Format Subgroup
acdvd, DVD: Adult/YA, ItemType, Media, Video Disc
```

Here's how it looks in the IntelliJ IDEA
[image]

Updated the code: changed seq[seq[string]] to String

```
def numberCheckoutRecordsPerFormat(checkoutDF: DataFrame, dataDictionaryDF: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

    val createFeatureVector = udf{(Format_Group:String, Format_Subgroup:String) => {
      dataDictionaryDF.map(x => if(Format_Group.flatten.contains(x)) 1.0 else 0.0)++Array(Format_Subgroup)
      }
    }
    checkoutDF
      .na.drop()
      .join(dataDictionaryDF
        .select($"Format_Group", $"Format_Subgroup", $"Code".as("ItemType"))
        , "ItemType")
      .withColumn("Format", createFeatureVector(dataDictionaryDF("Format_Group"), dataDictionaryDF("Format_Subgroup")))
      .groupBy("ItemBarCode")
      .agg(count("ItemBarCode"))
      .withColumnRenamed("count(ItemBarCode)", "CheckoutCount")
      .select($"Format", $"CheckoutCount")
  }
```

Furthermore, the numberCheckoutRecordsPerFormat should return a DataFrame of Format and number of Checkouts for a given item - but I got this part covered myself.

The data set used is the [Seattle Library Checkout Records](https://www.kaggle.com/seattle-public-library/seattle-library-checkout-records/version/1#Checkouts_By_Title_Data_Lens_2005.csv) from Kaggle

Thanks, people!

Comment: (1) Why are you using your Dataframe inside your UDF ? (2) Is ``Format_Subgroup:[String]`` supposed to compile ? (3) are you trying to mix Doubles with Strings with the ``++`` operator ?

Comment: I eventually figured out that it should probably be udf{(Format_Group:[String], Format_Subgroup:[String]), right?

Comment: And I'm not really good with UDFs hence this thread :)

Comment: It should look like ``val createFeatureVector = udf{(formatGroup:String, formatSubgroup:String) => ???}``

Comment: @baitmbarek Do you have any clues to what goes in the udf?

Comment: why don't you simply use the ``concat_ws`` built-in function, allowing you to concatenate your fields and eventually use a colon to get your ``Format Group:Format Subgroup`` expression

Comment: sounds doable. If you have a draft, feel free to add it as an answer so I can vote you up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doomdaam, you can try to use the `concat_ws` built-in function (always use built-in functions when possible). Your code will look like :

```
checkoutDF
      .na.drop()
      .join(dataDictionaryDF
        .select($"Format_Group", $"Format_Subgroup", $"Code".as("ItemType"))
        , "ItemType")
      .withColumn("Format", concat_ws(":",$"Format_Group", $"Format_Subgroup"))
      .groupBy("ItemBarCode")
      .agg(count("ItemBarCode"))
      .withColumnRenamed("count(ItemBarCode)", "CheckoutCount")
      .select($"Format", $"CheckoutCount")
```

Otherwise your UDF would have been :

```
val createFeatureVector = udf{(formatGroup:String, formatSubgroup:String) => Seq(formatGroup,formatSubgroup).mkString(":")}
```

Comment: I will test this later and let you know if it works!